# Firebase Storage databse

Tags: database, image, firebase, storage

I am trying to send an image to Firebase but do not want the user to select the image therefore i do not want them to upload any images. My image will come from the drawable. From looking at tutorials, i've only found a way of the user choosing to upload and send image. I tried to send the image through a click listener that i have implemented but i do not know which code allows it to send a specific image that i want to send. I have tried the getFile method but does not work. Can someone help me please. 
Here is my code :

```
 FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    DatabaseReference DR;
    private StorageReference storageReference;
    private FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fplank);

        firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        storageReference = firebaseStorage.getReference();
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        final StorageReference imageReference = storageReference.child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).child("Images").child("Milestone").child("Day");
        DR = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Activity").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid());
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Calorie").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid());

        start = (View)findViewById(R.id.start);
        startb = (View)findViewById(R.id.startB);
        starttext = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.startText);

        startb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int calorie = 90;
                int activity  = 1;

                UploadTask uploadTask = imageReference.getFile();
                databaseReference.setValue(calorie);
                DR.setValue(activity);
                startActivity(new Intent(FPlank.this, Score.class));
            }
        });
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please add an image of the database structure in your question

Comment: I've added an image of my storage on Firebase, is this fine?